# How to covert different datatypes in single column to integer in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert  different datatypes in age column to integer type as we can see the string, Na, and numeric type.

I tried the below code but isn't worked

```
train['age'].unique() 
train.age =train.age.str.replace(' ', '')
```

[image]

Comment: `train['age'].astype(int)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#converting to numeric
train.age = pd.to_numeric(train.age.str.strip(), errors='coerce')

#remove non numeric values
train = train.dropna(subset=['age'])

#convert to integers
train.age = train.age.astype(int)
```

Comment: train.age = train.age.str.strip().astype(int)

[![i did this im getting  error as " ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NA'
"we have na format values in it which should be removed before doing that, try to help me with the code which solves all condition like spaces in the columns , string format and na values ][1]][1]